# Finding empty Calender date slots

Tags: java, spring, date, calendar, compare

please help me i have java calendar date range like start date 2020-05-05 and end date 2020-05-22, and user will enter date range like

valid ranges :

1.start date 2020-05-07, end date 2020-05-10

2.start date 2020-05-11, end date 2020-05-15

3.start date 2020-05-16, end date 2020-05-17

4.start date 2020-05-18, end date 2020-05-18

And all are acceptable because none of the ranges are overlapping with other date range and following are invalid

Invalid date ranges :

1.start date 2020-05-06, end date 2020-05-08

2.start date 2020-05-07, end date 2020-05-08

Comment: What have you tried, and in which way did it not work? Which part of this task is unclear to you?

Comment: @Hulk it is like hotel booking start date and ecnd date should not overlap with given date range